# CakePHP 2.4.2: Comments Model Relations-Get Original Post's Title

Tags: cakephp, model, relationship, cakephp-2.1

I have a pretty typical Comment model where Comment belongsto many other models such as Article, Review, Photo, etc and in turn each of those models hasmany Comment. Here is how I built the relationship on the Comment model...

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Comment extends AppModel {

var $name = "Comment";


public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Article' => array(
        'className' => 'Article',
        'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Photo' => array(
        'className' => 'Photo',
        'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Review' => array(
        'className' => 'Review',
        'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
}
```

This works like a charm wherein if I'm viewing a particular article then I can retrieve all comments from that article and it works the same for the other models. **What I'm trying to do is show ALL recent comments with the original post's title no matter what model the original post is coming from** (Article, Review, Photo, etc) in the format of `$comment['Original']['title']`. I thought adding the below code within the belongsto of the Comment model would work but it does not....

```
    'Original' => array(
        'className' => 'Article',
        'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
        'conditions' => array('Comment.module_id' => 3),
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Original' => array(
        'className' => 'Review',
        'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
        'conditions' => array('Comment.module_id' => 2),
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Original' => array(
        'className' => 'Photo',
        'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
        'conditions' => array('Comment.module_id' => 8),
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
```

Unfortunately this only shows the correct title if the recent comment was on a photo `(Comment.module_id = 8)`.

Comment: Instead of editing your question with a whole new question, you should chalk this one off and ask another question as to why your contain isn't working as expected...etc

Comment: Please see question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205520/cakephp-2-4-2-contain-not-working-as-expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CakePHP's [Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) and do this:

```
//within a method of the Comment model
$recentComments = $this->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Article',
        'Photo',
        'Review',
        'User'
    ),
    'limit' => 10,
    'order' => $this->alias . '.created DESC'
));
```

Then, you'll get back the comments and any of their parents, regardless of which model it's in.  After that, as you repeat through each comment, you can either do a case statement, or an `if(!empty())` kinda thing to determine which model has content that you want to display.

(side note: not a good idea to create multiple associations with the same name per your attempt with "Original")

Comment: `'order' => $this->alias . '.created DESC'` was giving me an error. Had to change to `'order' => 'Comment.created DESC'`, the loop won't be as pretty but at least it works. Thanks.

Comment: ok I have 2 issues with this, please see edits in the question

Comment: this was the correct answer but it really slowed down my application because of how my database structure was set up. I had articles, reviews, photos, etc in different tables and a table called modules where each of these were a row and had a unique id. The comments table had a column called module_id. Now I moved everything to a posts table and continue to have a column called module_id this way if I have a sidebar and want to show the most recent articles I can just set my find conditions to module_id = 3. Anyways, now Post model has many Comment but Comment is just an alias back to Post.

Comment: Unless you have an insane amount of data, I would guess any slowness is due to incorrect table indexing (and/or lack of caching).  There shouldn't be an issue with keeping your database table structure as you'd hoped.

Comment: i have also added caching but it clears every 5 minutes so its very light. i have a lot of data. even when i did have my old method i used a little bit of caching and it lasted more like 30 minutes but it was incredibly slow. ive cut the speed by about 300%

Answer (score 0):

It's not surprising that you got comments only with conditions `Comment.module_id = 8`. You have made a basic PHP mistake. By using the same key `Original` multiple times you are effectively overwriting it's value each time. Choose unique aliases (array keys) for each association.

Comment: You're right, but this is just a reason it's not working - not an answer.  If he gives them each a different alias, then there's no reason to alias them at all - just use the model itself (per the answer I already gave).

Comment: "Choose unique aliases (array keys) for each association." That's the answer. An alias can either be same as model classname or different.